# Error joining two datatables in linq

Tags: vb.net, linq, join

I have the following code.

```
Dim hardlimit As DataTable = From f In dealDataTable.AsEnumerable
                                    Join f2 In hardlimithit.AsEnumerable
                                    On f.Field(Of Integer)("dea_ID") Equals f2.Field(Of Integer)("ID")
                                    Select f
```

I'm trying to select get all of the data from "dealDataTable" where the id matches my other datatable's id field.

I'm getting this error from this code.

```
System.InvalidCastException was caught
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Unable to cast object of type '<JoinIterator>d__61`4[System.Data.DataRow,System.Data.DataRow,System.Int32,System.Data.DataRow]' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.
  Source=FMSOvernight
  StackTrace:
       at FMSOvernight.Module1.RunLimitCalculations() in C:\Cloud Source Control\Funding Management Overnighter\FundingManagementSystemOvernightRoutine\Module1.vb:line 273
       at FMSOvernight.Module1.StartGeneration() in C:\Cloud Source Control\Funding Management Overnighter\FundingManagementSystemOvernightRoutine\Module1.vb:line 135
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting rows  so `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, that's not a `DataTable`. You can use [`CopyToDataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim hardlimitRows = From f In dealDataTable.AsEnumerable
                    Join f2 In hardlimithit.AsEnumerable
                    On f.Field(Of Integer)("dea_ID") Equals f2.Field(Of Integer)("ID")
                    Select f
Dim hardlimitTable = hardlimitRows.CopyToDataTable()
```

But note that this method throws an `InvalidOperationException` if there are no rows. You have to check that before. For example:

```
Dim hardlimitTable As DataTable = dealDataTable.Clone() ' empty table with the same columns '
If hardlimitRows.Any() Then
    hardlimitTable = hardlimitRows.CopyToDataTable()
End If
```